# Windows 10 Pro - Your Info shows Administrator - but permissions are limited

Tags: windows-10, permissions

Regardless of login via a local or Microsoft account, my permissions are limited, such as being unable to change the time zone via Date & Time Settings:

```
You do not have permission to perform this task. Please contact your computer administrator for help.
```

- Without any problem, I changed it within the Registry, but the annoying issue persists within Date & Time Settings:

  ```
  HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation
  ```

What options do I have to get full permissions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that your account is in the **Administrators** group. This can be done by checking the following:

1. Right-click the **Start** button and click **Computer Management**.
2. Navigate to **System Tools** > **Local Users and Groups** > **Groups**.
3. Double-click **Administrators** and confirm that your account is in that group.

If your account is in the Administrators group, you should be able to do the following:

1. Right-click the **Start** button and click **Command Prompt (Admin)**.
2. If prompted with a UAC dialog saying "Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your PC?", click **Yes**.
3. Type `net session`.
4. If you are an Administrator, you will get a result. If not, you will get 'Access Denied'.

Comment: This can be done by enabling and using the built-in Administrator account

Comment: I can see myself in admin group and only Windows PowerShell ( Admin) is visible on Start right-click . My understanding from Googling certain Windows 10 update does this replacement. Anyway PS>net session doesn't complain and gives "There are no entries in the list".

Comment: That has confirmed that you are a Local Administrator and have administrative access. Could you please give examples of some things you are trying that you get the error: "You do not have permission to perform this task" for? It may be that you need to 'Run as Administrator'. For example, to run Disk Management with elevated permissions, you right-click on **Start**, hold down **Shift** + **Ctrl**, and click **Disk Management**.

Comment: I noticed the glitch for Date & Time Settings ( I assume, it is Windows Store app ). It just doesn't change time zone, no warning or error. If try to change  it via Control Panel > Clock,Language, and Region > Change the time zone, it pops up Date and Time form. Click on button "Changing time zone" results in the error.  I updated my question as was able to change zone either directly in registry or by running tzutil.

Comment: The problem is my user is in the admin group but I get an error with `net session` you don't have acces

Comment: A more efficient means of determining group membership would be: `Net User $env:UserName` || `Net User %UserName%`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open "Local Security Policy" by running `secpol.msc`
2. Expand "Security Settings" → "Local Policies" → "User Rights Assignment".
3. In the right pane, double-click "**Change the system time**"
4. Check if "Administrators" group is in the list. If it's not there, click "Add User or Group..."
5. Click "Object Types"
6. Enable the checkbox for "Groups"
7. Click OK
8. In the "Enter the object names to select" text box, type "Administrators"
9. Click OK.

That's it. Users that belong to the "Administrators" group will now be able to change the system time on the local computer.

Default on workstations and servers:

- Administrators
- Local Service

Default on domain controllers:

- Administrators
- Server Operators
- Local Service